# SendGrid/Outlook receiving 50% of emails

Tags: node.js, outlook, sendgrid

I've just set up SendGrid, authentificated my domain and did the sender verification.

I use Node.js to send email via the API.

When I make a test, the mail is sent to my outlook address. It takes 3 seconds to appear in Outlook, not in spam, in my inbox.

However, when I make the same test, 30 seconds later, the mail is processed by SendGrid, but I never receive in Outlook..

How can it be possible ?

Comment: The problem seems to come from outlook.com because when I try with 2 messages back to back to an other email adress, it's working fine.

Comment: I have the same problem, How did you solve it? did you change your email provider?

Answer (score 0):

please check your sendgrid activity tab. Processed doesnt mean that outlook received it. After processed there is another level of delivered. Does it say in your sendgrid activity log that it was delivered. It might say not and outlook refused it because they think one email after the other might be spam. (Keep this in mind when sendgrid sends emails it doesnt come from your email address, and some might mark that as spam)